# Why does my sound created in Alchemy play endlessly?

Tags: synthesizer, logic-pro, macbook-pro

I am creating a sound using the Alchemy synthesizer in Logic Pro X. When I play a note to hear the sound, it goes on forever.

Why could that be happening?

[image]

Comment: How are you triggering the sound, via a MIDI region in Logic Pro X or via a MIDI controller keyboard (or similar)?

Comment: Also try setting "Hold" to zero in the AHDSR envelope settings and see what that does.

Comment: @SimonBosley I'm using the MacBook keyboard!

Comment: @ToddWilcox yep, it's set to zero, no luck :/

Comment: I would say that changing the release would be more helpful than changing the hold, but I see it's not set very high anyway. Is the synth going though any other processing afterwards? Separate reverb or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

Click the master volume Knob and it will bring up the corresponding modulation routing make sure the ADSR is routing to the Volume.